# DQL searching MD5 string?

Tags: doctrine-orm

How do I search my database using DQL for a MD5 string.

I'm using doctrine and want to write the following query in DQL.

```
SELECT * FROM club_members WHERE md5( CONCAT('secret_key',id)) = '8e801b9cd9b38c142472d5fc5238f538'
```

I tried

```
$dql = "SELECT c FROM models\Club_members c WHERE md5( CONCAT('".$secret_key."',c.id)) = '8e801b9cd9b38c142472d5fc5238f538'";
```

but get a fatal error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 52: Error: Expected known function, got 'md5'' in //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:42 Stack trace: #0 //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(396): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::syntaxError('line 0, col 52:...') #1 //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2778): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('known function', Array) #2 //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2311): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->FunctionDeclaration() #3 //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2279): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticPrimary() #4 //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2247): Doctrine\ORM\Query in //application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 42

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 is not included into standard Doctrine, you need to install MD5 extension: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Md5.php